# JUNIT Test Console Output Displays under wrong test name IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a handful of test cases that run and displays an output to console. However, in the JUnit test displays the console output under the wrong test case.

Anyone have this problem with IntelliJ-IDEA 14?

Comment: Can you provide the tests and the output?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66683

Comment: I've encountered the same problem in the most recent version of IntelliJ, that is 14.3

Comment: I'm getting this in Intellij IDEA 2016.1.1